# MVC ViewBag with url removes all the symbols when view has loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I'm trying to display/return a url using a viewbag. I get this on the Action as the value of the ViewBag:

```
http:\\www.mysite.com\\images\\logo.jpg
```

But whenever the view gets loaded all the slash gets removed and would end up with this:

```
http:wwwmysitecomimageslogo.jpg
```

EDIT: For Code on generating the LogoUrl.

EDIT 2: This is how I pull it out of the db, I use context and pull it out using EF, how else do you pull it out?

```
ViewBag.LogoUrl = context.Event.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id).LogoUrl;
```

This is how I know what gets pulled:

```
string url = context.Event.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id).LogoUrl;

ViewBag.LogoUrl = url;
```

This is how I use it:

```
var logoUrl;
$('#logo').click(function (event) {
        <% if(ViewBag.LogoUrl != null) { %>
            logoUrl = '<%: ViewBag.LogoUrl %>';
        <% } %>

           :
           :
           :
     return false;
 }
```

Make sense?

Comment: just updated the post

Comment: This is not what @SLaks meant by **"Show us your code"**. You show how you pull your url from the db. not how you display it in your view.